# Unable to access nested remoting apis created with "nestRemoting": true for belongsTo

Tags: prototype, loopbackjs, loopback

I am unable to access the nested prototype to disable it or make changes to the implementation logic.

Following is the Org.json and OrgGroup.json

Org.json

```
{
  "name": "Org",
  "plural": "Orgs",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "replaceOnPUT": true,
    "validateUpsert": false
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "orgGroup": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "OrgGroup",
      "foreignKey": "groupId",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": true
      }
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

OrgGroup.json

```
{
  "name": "OrgGroup",
  "plural": "OrgGroups",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "orgs": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Org",
      "foreignKey": "groupId",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": true
      }
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

I have an access method like this :
`GET /Orgs/{id}/orgGroup` 
I am able to capture this using `'prototype.__get__orgGroup'`

But the `"nestRemoting": true` is creating as expected the following due to the relations:

```
GET /Orgs/{id}/orgGroup/orgs
GET /Orgs/{id}/orgGroup/orgs/{fk}
PUT /Orgs/{id}/orgGroup/orgs/{fk}
```

I want to access this nested api for 1) disabling the PUT method `PUT /Orgs/{id}/orgGroup/orgs/{fk}` and provide acl's for `GET /Orgs/{id}/orgGroup/orgs/{fk}`. However, I am unable to do it. How do I do it?

None of the the following works:

Eg: For the nested api `GET /Orgs/{id}/orgGroup/orgs` , I have tried:

```
    prototype._get_orgGroup_orgs
    prototype.__get__orgGroup_orgs
    prototype.__find__orgGroup_orgs
    prototype._find_orgGroup_orgs
    __get__orgGroup_orgs
    __get__orgGroup__orgs
__get__orgGroupOrgs
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```js
Org.disableRemoteMethodByName('prototype.__updateById__ OrgGroups')
```

Comment: I am able to block the first level nesting - `'prototype.__get__orgGroup'` for `GET /Orgs/{id}/orgGroup`. But when I try to access `GET /Orgs/{id}/orgGroup/orgs` - second level nesting it does not aloow me to access using `prototype.__get__orgGroup_orgs` nor `prototype.__get__orgGroup__get__orgs` nor `prototype.__get__orgGroup_get_orgs` nor `prototype.__get__orgGroup_orgs`.